# How to move data to SQLite?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

Code

```
public class SettingsContacts extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView contactsList;
private List<ContactsHelper> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_contacts);

    contactsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    //Add the data first
    addDataToList();
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    //and then create a object and pass the lis
    mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);

    contactsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    contactsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    contactsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}

public void addDataToList() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id},
                            null);
                    if (phoneCursor != null) {
                        if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                            String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                            contacts.add(new ContactsHelper(name, phoneNumber));
                            phoneCursor.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
}
```

This displays all the contacts in the users phone in an activity... How do i move the data into a table in SQLite?

Progress so far:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Table Name
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts";

// Table columns
public static final String ID = "ID";
public static final String Contact_Name = "Contact_Name";
public static final String Phone_Number = "Phone_Number";

// Database Information
static final String DB_NAME = "MessagePlus_Contacts";

// database version
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

// Creating table query
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Contact_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Phone_Number + " INT NOT NULL);";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
 }
```

Helper

```
public class ContactsHelper {
private String Name;
private String PhoneNumber;

public ContactsHelper() {
}

public ContactsHelper(String Name, String PhoneNumber) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return PhoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String PhoneNumber) {
    this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
}
```

}

I've got to this point but I don't know how to proceed because I have so far only worked with adding/modifying data by clicking a button or similar to that.

How do I move the complete data to SQLite and when new contact is added obviously it wont get added to table automatically so when I add a feature like swipe to refresh I want the new contact to be added to the data as well?

Comment: Instead of writing all this on your own, i would suggest you to use a ORM like [requery](https://github.com/requery/requery) or  [greendao](https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO).

Comment: You need to make a function which accepts data and has a SQL query to add all data.

Comment: How do i do that? @UmangBurman

Comment: You can use Room, it's a Google library and it will make things very simple and easy for you: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Please refer to this tutorial: https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I know how to add and update... but i dont know how to add all the contacts list to the table @UmangBurman

Comment: @MichelleKinsten You mean you know to add single data, but not all at a time.?

Comment: Yeah @UmangBurman

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer for you. @MichelleKinsten

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Please post your `Model` class

Comment: @MichelleKinsten `addDataToList()` is already adding the data to the database. I think you are not able to see the data on the UI?

Comment: I can see the data @UmangBurman

Comment: Also look to the edited question i posted model class

Comment: That code is just for fetching Contacts from the phone and displaying it in recycler view... i want to take that data and put it in a table

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Please check and Tell me if it's working or any error. Please follow the steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Add this method in your `DatabaseHelper` class:

```
public void insertData(String contactName, String phoneNumber) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(DatabaseHelper.Contact_Name, contactName);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.Phone_Number, phoneNumber);

    db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    // close db connection
    db.close();

}
```

then, Firstly, make `DatabaseHelper` global object in your `SettingsContacts` class:

```
public DatabaseHelper database;
```

Add this in your`onCreate()`

```
database = new DatabaseHelper(SettingsContacts.this);
```

then after this, add the below line in `addDataToList()` method as shown:

Add this line:

```
database.insertData(name, phoneNumber)
```

as shown in below code (Write Here):

```
if (phoneCursor != null) {
    if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
         String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

          contacts.add(new ContactsHelper(name, phoneNumber));
          phoneCursor.close();

          ....... (Write Here)

     }
}
```

That's it.

Hope it works.

To see if the data is already inserted, you can check the count of your table:

```
public int getCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + DatabaseHandler.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return count;
}
```

Write the above method in you Database Handler class.

Then, in your activity after calling `insertData(..)`, you can write like:

```
int count = database.getCount();
Log.e("Count From DB: ", String.valueOf(count));
```

Comment: How can i check the table? Like Show table contents?

Comment: You must write another query for that.. @MichelleKinsten like "Select * from ...."

Comment: Getting a null pointer exception on the line 
database.insertData(name, phoneNumber);

Comment: Did you add this line in onCreate() : `database = new DatabaseHelper(SettingsContacts.this);`

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Can you show me the updated `onCreate()` please? I mean after you added that

Comment: Oh wait my bad i had initialised after i called the method... But does this code mean that all the contacts are in the database??? And the newly added ones will also be added once i open the activity?

Comment: @MichelleKinsten This line: `database = new DatabaseHelper(SettingsContacts.this);` should be just after `setContentView(...)` line.

Comment: Yeah i did that

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Yes the above code means what all contacts you have in `RecyclerView` they are in database. Yes, The newly added ones will also be added in your db when activity opens.

Comment: Can i just check once? Ik the statment is Select * from <TableName> but where should i put that for the table to be displayed in the logcat or something???

Comment: @MichelleKinsten I've updated my answer (The last part) to check the count of DB Values

Comment: Its not showing anything... I tried with a toast also but still nothing
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(count), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

Comment: And not displaying toast at all... its weird

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Data is inserting for sure. You can try calling that count method in a button click listener and see